# Constructing a sequence such that specific properties are met

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose we are asked to show that given any $L \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence of reals $\{{s_n}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that two properties are met: one is that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} s_n = L$ and second is that $n \neq m \implies s_n \neq s_m$ (where $n, m$ are not defined at 0). How do you even think about a question like that, let alone solve it. I know that the sum can be defined as limit of partial sums that is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} s_n = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} S_k = L$. I dont know where to go next.

Comment: How about the terms in a converging [geometric series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)? The sum will obviously converge and you can make one where each term is unique.

Comment: @kimchilover sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

I'll focus on the question of how you might go about coming up with a solution. One thing you can often do with a question like this is ask a less general version of the same question. Instead of right away trying to find a series that works for any value of $L$, just try and find a single value of $L$ that you can solve. What's a convergent series where all the terms are different?

You can try thinking about the first few series that you learned about: $0+0+0+\dots$, or $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots$, or $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \dots$. The first one converges, but it won't work because not all of the terms are different. The second one is no good either: it diverges. But $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \dots$ is a nice geometric series, and it converges to 1. Each term takes you half of the remaining distance. And all the terms are different, as required. So we've solved the problem for $L=1$:

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \dots = 1$$

Let's try a different case, $L=3$. You might not have encountered a series before that works for this case, but with a little bit of thought, you will see that you can make one from the previous solution, just by multiplying both sides by 3:

$$\frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{8} + \dots = 3$$

Once you've come up with that trick, it's easy to see how to do almost all the real numbers:

$$\frac{L}{2} + \frac{L}{4} + \frac{L}{8} + \dots = L$$

I say almost all, because this won't work for $L=0$. (It works fine for negative numbers.) If $L=0$ then all the terms in the series become 0, and so we fail the requirement that the terms be different from each other. So you'll need to handle the special case when $L=0$. (Hint: Try coming up with some other small modification to the series $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \dots$)

Comment: And as for negative reals would it just be $\frac{-L}{2}+\frac{-L}{4} + \frac{-L}{8} + \cdots = -L$?

Comment: for $L = 0$, would the series just be $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{8} + \cdots = 0$?

Comment: Yes for the negative reals. For $L=0$ you've got the right idea, but all the fractions after the 1 should be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Take $J > |L|$. Define $s_1 = J + L$ and $s_i = -J 2^{1 - i}$ for $i \geq 2$.